# A Glowing White hot chair a man is forced to sit on

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, werewolf

This I believe may have been one story from an anthology.

The horrific image has been with me from the early 70's. I remember a metal chair is heated over a fire until it glows. A man is brought forward, stripped and forced to sit on the chair. He is basically cooked. A hand reaches out and pulls a lump of cooked flesh from the burned man and eats it.

I think this was a werewolf story, or the other stories had a werewolf theme.

This, as I said, I read in the 70's.

Comment: That's a fairly standard form of torture called an [iron chair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_chair). This might be a direct reference to the [Westphalia werewolf case](http://www.medievalwarfare.info/torture.htm)

Comment: One fictional depiction can be found in the [Pine Deep trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_Deep_Trilogy) with Griswold, who is Stubbes.

Comment: The Pine Deep Trilogy is a little too late. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I remember this also from my youth in the 70's; clearly it affected us both for this image to endure. as a youth I would have been reading from the classic horror genre : I think it was a vampire tale.